# filter and append AJAX JSON result based on objects with a specific key value

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to display the 3 records that have the value  "sort":"list:"

I've tried the two methods below of using an if statement to filter results, (commented out below) to display the 3 records but both methods did not render any results to the screen?  With the lines commented out as below the page correctly renders all 5 results.  Any advice is appreciated THANKS!

```
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: '/stores',
success: function(stores) {
  // if (stores.sort === 'list') {
  $.each(stores, function(i, store) {
    // if (stores.sort === 'list'){
      $stores.append(`<div><img src="${store.name}.jpg"></div>`);
    //  }
     });
  //}
   }
 });
```

My JSON is pretty simple:

```
[
 {
 "_id": "5be78df2fb6fc06239e0c39b",
 "name": "Albertsons",
 "sort": "list"
 },
 {
 "_id": "5be78e00fb6fc06239e0c39c",
 "name": "COSTCO",
 "sort": "list"
 },
 {
 "_id": "5be78e17fb6fc06239e0c3ac",
 "name": "Food Lion",
 "sort": "bank"
 },
 {
 "_id": "5be78e34fb6fc06239e0c3b1",
 "name": "7Eleven",
 "sort": "list"
 },
 {
 "_id": "5be78e5ffb6fc06239e0c3b7",
 "name": "Kroger",
 "sort": "bank"
 }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stores` is the *entire* response, which is an array, not an individual object you're iterating over, so `stores.sort` won't be meaningful. Check the `store` property instead:

```
success: function(stores) {
  $.each(stores, function(i, store) {
    if (store.sort === 'list'){
      $stores.append(`<div><img src="${store.name}.jpg"></div>`);
    }
  });
}
```

Or, you might `filter` beforehand instead:

```
success: function(stores) {
  const listStores = stores.filter(({ sort }) => sort === 'list');
  listStores.forEach(({ name }) => {
    $stores.append(`<div><img src="${name}.jpg"></div>`);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$.grep` to filter out the objects you want.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var jsonString = '[{"_id": "5be78df2fb6fc06239e0c39b","name": "Albertsons","sort":"list"},{"_id": "5be78e00fb6fc06239e0c39c","name": "COSTCO","sort": "list"},{"_id": "5be78e17fb6fc06239e0c3ac","name": "Food Lion","sort": "bank"},{"_id": "5be78e34fb6fc06239e0c3b1","name": "7Eleven","sort": "list"},{"_id": "5be78e5ffb6fc06239e0c3b7","name": "Kroger","sort": "bank"}]'
var jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonString);

// Filter your object using grep
var filteredObjects = $.grep(jsonObject, function(a){
 return a.sort == "list"
});

var elements = '';
for(var i = 0; i<filteredObjects.length; i++ ){
  elements += '<div>'+filteredObjects[i].name+'</div>'
}
$('#container').append(elements);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```